# Understanding init() when sub-classing in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, subclass, init

How can I add a custom initializer when inheriting from a class that already has an initializer?

What I have is a `Vehicle` class which has an itializer who takes an argument `name`. What I want to do is inherit from this `Vehicle`class, create another initializer for the new class but keep using the existing initializer.

### Base Class (No problem here):

```
class Vehicle{
    var make:String
    init(make:String){
     self.make = make
    }
}
```

### New Class (Doesn't work):

```
// Not sure how to structure this class     
class Car:Vehicle {
    var engine:Double

    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    init(engine:Double){
        self.engine = engine
    }
}
```

This is what I would like to be able to do... re-use the existing initializer plus the new one.

```
let cobalt = Car(make:"Chevy" engine: 2.5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any designated initializer in a subclass must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass:

> **Initializer Delegation for Class Types**
>
> To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience
>   initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation
>   calls between initializers:
>
> Rule 1 A designated initializer **must call a designated initializer
>   from its immediate superclass**
>
> ...

From the [Swift Language Guide - Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Hence, you could construct your designated initializer of `Car` to take two arguments, `make` and `engine`, and use the latter to inititalize the member property `engine` of the subclass, thereafter call the designated initializer of the superclass using the supplied `make` parameter (supplied to subclass initializer) as argument to the superclass initializer.

```
class Car: Vehicle {
    var engine: Double

    init(make: String, engine:Double){
        self.engine = engine
        super.init(make: make)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks a lot. Why is the `override` modifier omitted on this case?

Comment: `Vehicle` doesn't have a declaration matching `init(make: String, engine:Double)`, so you aren't overriding anything. You only use `override` when the child class's declaration matches a declaration of the parent, to inform the compiler that you're aware you're actually overriding an existing declaration.